# mysql - select from one table if not in the other , else select from the other one

Tags: mysql

I have two tables : **phone** and **session_phone** . Both the tables have the column called phone_number .

Now i want to check if the phone number exists in the table **session_phone** , if not then select a random phone number from the table **phone** . But if the phone number exists , it should select the phone number from the table session_phone .

Below is my query which doesnt seem to work .

```
    select case when b.phone_number is null then a.phone_number else b.phone_number end 'phone_number'
from phone a left join session_phone b on 
a.phone_number = b.phone_number and a.user_group = b.user_group 
order by rand() limit 1
```

The issue with the above query is that , even if the phone number is present in **session_phone** , it gives me other numbers from the table **phone**.

Please advice.Thanks.

Sample Data :

In table **phone** , phone numbers are : 1111,2222,3333,4444
In table **session_phone** ,the phone number is : 2222

Output should be (since i order by **rand()** and limit 1) : 2222

Comment: Can you add sample data and the expected result?

Comment: I think you should change your `from phone a left join session_phone b` to vice versa

Comment: @Jens - I have added the sample data and output . Thanks.

Comment: *"Now i want to check if the phone number exists.."* - Which phone number? It's easy to write a query that returns `2222`, but I don't think you've specified the exact rules very well, and it's unclear what behaviour you want when session_phone contains 0 or more than 1 row, or when `limit` is raised.

Comment: possible duplicate of of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28452562/mysql-case-statement-get-default-records

Comment: Here are the rules , for a user id , i need to check if the phone number exists in the table session_phone , if it does then select that phone number , but if it doesn't then select a random phone number from the table phone . This is all about it.

Comment: @dhams - If you didn't get the question its okay . But do not call it a duplicate without even knowing my query .

Comment: its same issue with case you asked for and for that you have to read duplicate properly

Answer (score 0):

The simplest query that does the job is probably:

```
select coalesce(s.phone_number, p.phone_number)
from (select * from phone order by rand() limit 1) p
left join session_phone s on s.phone_number = ?
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b2e7/4)

This works by getting 1 random row from phone and left-joining it to a possible hit in session_phone, which will be null if there's no hit. Coalesce returns the first non-null value in the list, so if there's a hit you get it, if no hit you get the random one.